# Prove that $\beta>0$ in an equality obtained by the Hahn Banach theorem

Tags: calculus, analysis, solution-verification, convex-analysis

I consider $ J : K\to\mathbb{R}$ where $K$ is a convex and closed subset of $V$ an Hilbert space and $J$ is convex and continuous.

I define

$$
\text{Epi}(J) = \{ (\lambda, v)\in\mathbb{R}\times K: J(v)\leq\lambda\}
$$

Considering $(\lambda_0, v_0)$ not in $\text{Epi}(J)$. $\text{Epi}(J)$ is closed and convex for the topology and vector space structure induced by the Cartesian product of $\mathbb{R}\times V$ : we can use the Hahn Banach theorem that gives  the following inequality for all $(\lambda, v)\in\text{Epi}(J)$.

$$
L(v) + \beta\lambda > \alpha > L(v_0) + \beta\lambda_0
$$

Where $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ and $L\in V’$.

From this, I want to prove that $\beta>0$. Here is my approach :

We have $J(v_0)\geq J(v_0)$. So $(J(v_0), v_0)\in\text{Epi}(J)$. Then we have

$$
L(v_0) - L(v_0) + \beta(J(v_0) -\lambda_0) > 0\implies \beta(J(v_0) - \lambda_0) > 0
$$

And we conclude since $J(v_0)>\lambda_0$.

Is this seems correct please ?

Comment: epigraph is not compact (only if it is empty)

Comment: Thank you for your comment,  it was a mistake, it is closed